# Huge scroll view layout slows the application

Tags: android, android-activity, scrollview

I am getting some problem in a scroll view in my project. I have to fill up a huge form in my application. I put them in a scroll view. I have more than 70 rows in that scroll view.
The problem is the activity getting slowed down,when I am trying to insert in the edit text it performs very very slow.When the activity is loaded it takes too much time to display the screen.
I know there are lots of views in a single activity, for this it is getting slow.
But in my application I need to implement this form in a single activity within the scroll.
Can anyone suggest me any better idea to implement this.

Santanu

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of rows, can you not put them in a ListView which takes care of its own scrolling. I have a few hundred rows in a list view and it scrolls very quickly. Also, use the 'Holder' pattern to re-use individual views. Here's a good reference to the [holder pattern](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But in my application all rows are not similar, there are spinner, check box, radio button, edit text etc. in different rows. If rows are small in number it can be handled in getView, but here lots of rows , I don't know how it can be handled.I have used Table layout to implement this form.

Comment: It doesn't metter, your getView() can return spinner for pos 0, button for pos 1, two checkboxes in linear layout for pos 2, etc

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use Custome ListView for This.[Read This Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Answer (score 0):

What do You think about creating list view activity and implement your controls via list items . In this case You should overwrite getView for list view adapter (particular view implementation for each control (pos 0 - first control, pos 1 second ... etc, using switch statement or something like this )

benefits of this approach is "lasy" control creation : list view will create only items it can show on screen, other views will be created "on Demand"

create following array with layout Ids:
    `int[] layouts = new int[]{R.layout.button_layout, R.layout.spinner_layout,    R.layout.two_checkboxes, ... etc}`

and create layout files for each item separately. then inflate them on particular position in getView method.